# Order of IPN returns when setting up subscriptions

Tags: paypal-ipn

Gidday

I'm setting up several subscribe buttons on my site, each without a free trial period, so the initial two IPNs, subscr_signup and subscr_payment are sent about the same time. I'm using the custom field in the IPN to hold the user's membership ID from my site (subscription is separate from signing up for an account).

I've read that Paypal doesn't always send those two IPNs them in that order.

Initially I was going to use the subscr_signup IPN to populate the member's subscription details, but I'm wondering, am I better off using the subscr_payment IPN to do that ie check if a sub has been set up, and if not set one up, otherwise just check the subscr_payment details against the database?

The payment IPN doesn't have the recurring field, but I don't need it, as all subscriptions are recurring on my site, and I can determine the type of subscription from the amount paid.

Or, would it be better if I set it up as a 1 day free trial, so the IPNs definitely come separately?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Either way should work.  Another option that some merchants have done, is written all of the information to their database and set up the account before sending the buyer over to PayPal to sign up and make the payment.  Then the merchants would rely on the IPN to actually activate the IPN or activate it beyond it's free trial period.  You could also set up a script to check your system periodically to see if there are any profiles that are deactivated and should be removed from your system, or that never paid.

Comment: Thanks Chad. Currently, I sign people up to a free 90 day account (no payment info required), and then they have the option of signing into their account, & subscribing to turn that account into a paid service, thus continuing their membership (+ they get extra features). Is the way you're describing possible even though I'm not asking for Paypal signup at the beginning of that trial? Part two in next comment...

Comment: The way I understand your reply, when user is ready, they convert their account to a paid one which comes with more free trial time (ie 1 day I guess?), and the subscr_signup IPN listener updates the user's info to the DB. then when the first payment comes in 24hrs later, the second IPN activates the account. Right? I wanted the extra features I offer to start as soon as they sign up for the paid account, but I could let them have the extra features for a week after signup regardless if payment comes in, which would give plenty of time for the 2nd IPN to activate the account. Is this possible?